# Cursor' object has no attribute '_last_executed' when using in a transaction

Tags: mysql, django, transactions

I am creating a few entries in my MySQL Db.

```
class Images(models.Model):
    isactive = models.BooleanField(_('Active Flag'), default=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

These images can be associated with model class Bike.

Now I am creating a lot of bikes and trying to do that in a transaction so that all the objects are created or none.

```
    @transaction.atomic
    def create_in_db(**kwargs):
        try:
            bike = Bike(**bikedata)
            bike.save()
            create_others(data)  
            #create some other related models(If they fail I don't want Bike as well)
            create_images(bikeimages, bike)
        except Exception as e:
            #log errors
            raise e

def create_images(images, related_to_obj):
    for image in images.values():
        try:
            image['content_object'] = related_to_obj
            image['user'] = user
            i = Image(**image)
            i.save()
        except Exception as e:
            #log errors 
            pass
```

In case the image is already present in db on calling `i.save()` it throws an `Integrity Error`, which I catch. Skipping some images is not an issue here. But after I get an `Integrity error` the remaining `i.save()` throw `Cursor' object has no attribute '_last_executed'` and neither the images are created nor the bike.

If I remove the `@transaction.atomic` line everything works fine and the images that throw an `Intergrity Error` are not created and the remaining images are associated with a `Bike` object and persisted to the DB.